# What is causing the consistent 45s delay between when my Django LiveServerTestCase starts and when the test server is available for connection?

Tags: python, django, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I run `./manage.py test myapp.tests.SlowTestCase` using the code below, there is a consistent, approximately 45 second delay between when the test starts and when the test server (http://127.0.0.1:8081) responds. Any attempts to visit the test server hang until the 45 second period is over.

I have definitely ruled out database creation and fixtures as the issue, and I am unable to hit the test server with other browsers. When the test browser opens, I'm able to visit other URLs immediately.

What am I doing wrong? Is it normal for the test server to take this long to start up? This delay makes it nearly impossible to develop tests locally in an efficient way. Thank you for reading.

```py
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver import firefox


class SeleniumTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(SeleniumTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.wd = firefox.webdriver.WebDriver()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.wd.quit()
        super(SeleniumTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()


class SlowTestCase(SeleniumTestCase):

    def test_slow(self):

        self.wd.get('http://127.0.0.1:8081')
```